Who introduced the fermionic creation and annihilation operators?
It is strange that this is never mentioned when textbooks introduce the 2nd quantization formalism.

Wikipedia, Creation and annihilation operators, top paragraph:"They were introduced by Paul Dirac." And they reference his paper The quantum theory of the emission and absorption of radiation, Proc Roy Soc London, Ser A, 114 (767), 1927, 243-265.
